# Launching ios app on real device with appium gives error with ideviceinstaller

Tags: device, appium

I'm tring to run appium tests on real device, but it fails at this step:

```
.
.
.
info: [debug] App is not installed. Will try to install the app.
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u 688d4920c35beee00c151029f0ec4fc177c2de08 -i /Users/a8/Myapp/capture_page_response_time/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Myapp.app
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libusbmuxd.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/libimobiledevice/lib/libimobiledevice.6.dylib
  Reason: image not found

info: [debug] Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u 688d4920c35beee00c151029f0ec4fc177c2de08 -i /Users/a8/Myapp/capture_page_response_time/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Myapp.app
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libusbmuxd.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/libimobiledevice/lib/libimobiledevice.6.dylib
  Reason: image not found

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u 688d4920c35beee00c151029f0ec4fc177c2de08 -i /Users/a8/Myapp/capture_page_response_time/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Myapp.app\ndyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libusbmuxd.4.dylib\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/libimobiledevice/lib/libimobiledevice.6.dylib\n  Reason: image not found\n)","killed":false,"code":null,"signal":"SIGTRAP","cmd":"/bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u 688d4920c35beee00c151029f0ec4fc177c2de08 -i /Users/a8/Myapp/capture_page_response_time/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Myapp.app","origValue":"Command failed: /bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u 688d4920c35beee00c151029f0ec4fc177c2de08 -i /Users/a8/myapp/test/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Myapp.app\ndyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libusbmuxd.4.dylib\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/libimobiledevice/lib/libimobiledevice.6.dylib\n  Reason: image not found\n"},"sessionId":null}
```

What am i missing? I did install ideviceinstaller manually.
I'm using Xcode: 7.2, Appium: 1.3.13, iPhone: 5s, 6 , iOS 9.0

I saw similar posts, but did not find a solution that could help me.
One being: [Appium iOS real device - issue with ideviceinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232314/appium-ios-real-device-issue-with-ideviceinstaller)

Comment: have you ran `./reset.sh --ios --real-safari`?

Comment: No, i didn't. which directory do I do this? (I've to run the tests on iOS app )

Comment: Posted an answer with explanation. If you need more detail, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Run `./reset.sh --ios --real-safari`

the reset.sh file should be in the appium directory.

Hope this helps,
Liam

Comment: Here is what it get:  * Determining platform
* Platform is mac
---- Resetting / Initializing Appium ----
RESETTING NPM
* Installing new or updated NPM modules (including devDeps)
RESETTING GENERAL
* Nothing to do, not a git repo
RESETTING IOS
---------------------------------------------------
WARNING: you do not appear to have iOS7/8 SDK active
---------------------------------------------------
* Setting iOS config to Appium's version
* Building SafariLauncher for real devices
---- FAILURE: reset.sh exited with status 1 ----
---- Retry with --verbose to see errors ----

Comment: `Warning: you do not appear have iOS7/8 SDK active`. Do you have xCode installed and updated?